# Close existing toplevel when a new is created. Tkinter Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, window, tk-toolkit, toplevel

Ive got a button in a program that opens a toplevel window.
If the button is pressed again I want the old toplevel to be destroyed and a new one to be created. I've searched for hours and tried implementing different ways but nothing seems to work.

Ive tried these approaches in various forms:

```
if toplevel is None or not toplevel.winfo_exists():
    toplevel.destroy()


try:
    toplevel.destroy()
except:
    pass


if toplevel.winfo_exists() == "1":
    toplevel.destroy()
```

My code looks like this:

```
def translate():
        #(I would like to check for and close existing toplevels here)
        toplevel = Toplevel()
        ...stuff
```

I greatly appreciate all the help I can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `translate`, `toplevel` is a local variable. You need to make it global if you wish to access it outside of `translate` and you aren't using classes.

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan, it works! I was hoping you would stop by as I've seen your answer similar questions when I searched.


For people reading this wondering what I did, I just added "global toplevel" before the "try, except"